# OpsHub errors OH-SCM-003 and OH-SCM-002 - Resolution description is unclear

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-migration, opshub

I am receiving the following errors during an OpsHub migration. I do not know what entity to which the error message refers, nor how to sync it or remove the mapping, nor where such a mapping would exist. Any help is greatly appreciated. I also appreciate the free migration tool. Thanks.

OH-SCM-003: Unable to fetch destination entity id for source entity Internal Id: 1, Global Id: 3980, Error: OH-SCM-002: Entity with Internal Id 1, Global Id 3980 from  STOP_Repo__TFS_Source_1406759539789_ALM_TFS_14067595397911406759539805 has not been synced into destination system yet. Please sync the entity or remove entity mapping to continue sync process.

#opshub 
 #visual-studio-online

Comment: As we were giving up for the night an item in the OpsHub log files pointed us to work items linked to change sets from different TFS projects. We are removing the links on the source TFS server, but not sure how long to wait on the "retry" as it never seems to happen. Thousands of change sets and work items and no way to find out which ones are borked - this could be a long night. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this error due to Associated work item 1 not found on VSO.
Can please verify that associated work item (1) is from different project than the project selected for migration?

If this the case, you will require to migrate again. Configure new migration with all those project for which you have association in your change set.

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response! Our work around: We created a migration for just the work items for these two cross-linked projects. After all the work items were migrated we created a migration for just the change sets and included both projects in the migration again. Started the migration and went home. We arrived in the office this morning and the change set migration had completed with zero errors. We could not have achieved the migration w/o OpsHub.